# Finding integral of $2 \lambda\int_0^{\infty} x^{2n}xe^{-\lambda x^2} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, statistics

Finding integral of $$2 \lambda\int_0^{\infty} x^{2n}xe^{-\lambda x^2} \ dx$$

using integral by parts I get that Finding integral of $$2 \lambda\int_0^{\infty} x^{2n}xe^{-\lambda x^2} \ dx = \dfrac{n}{\lambda} \cdot \dfrac{n-1}{\lambda} \int_0^\infty x^{2n-4} \cdot x e^{-\lambda x^2} \ dx$$

so I assume that $$2 \lambda\int_0^{\infty} x^{2n}xe^{-\lambda x^2} \ dx = \dfrac{n!}{\lambda^n}$$. How can I formally prove this?

Comment: set $x^2 =y $, then integrate by parts. Or use induction, or the definition of the Gamma function,or the differentiate wrt. a parameter....there are thousends of ways to proff this...

Comment: @tired that's not really helpful, I didn't ask how many ways there are to prove it, rather just help on any particular one.

Comment: ...therefore i gave u some ideas i which directions one can think

Comment: what would happen if go integrate by parts further?

Comment: I'd get $\frac{n}{\lambda} \cdot \frac{n-1}{\lambda} \cdot \frac{n-2}{\lambda} \cdot \int_0^\infty x^{2n-6}\cdot x e^{-\lambda x^2} \ dx$ etc

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I could use induction~?

Comment: Ok now repeat this procedure until $2n-2m=0$ , where $m$ is the number of ibp. you used

Comment: I don't really follow, that is what I'm asking - how can I arrange this

Comment: integrate by parts $n-$times

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: hmmm, where is the problem then...you are exactly on the right track

Comment: I'm trying to present it formally: I know that if we let $I_n = \int_0^\infty y^n e^{\lambda y} \ dy$ then we are trying to figure out $\lambda I_n$. We have $\lambda I_n = nI_{n-1} = n \cdot \frac{n-1}{\lambda} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{2}{\lambda} \cdot  I_0$ then $I_0 = 1/\lambda$ gives the result. I am trying to prove this formula formally. All I have done is prove the first 3-4 terms.

Comment: Perfect! why you don't just repeat this process $n$-times ?  Or is this not formal enough? Then use induction ..

Comment: @tired What would be the induction statement? This is what I'm having troubles with. Suppose I know $I_n = \frac{n}{\lambda}I_{n-1}$ and I prove it by induction. Then how do I conclude that $I_n = \frac{n!}{\lambda^n}$

Comment: I would assume that $I_{n-1}=\frac{(n-1)!}{\lambda^{n-1}}$ then i would integrate $I_n$ by parts one time and see what i get...

Comment: @tired I don't quite follow. I don't get what inductions tatement you are using.

Comment: $I_1=1$ and $I_{n-1}$ as  above as  induction hypothesis. the induction step is to go from $n-1$ to $n$

Comment: So the induction hypothesis is $I_n = n!/\lambda^{n}$?

Comment: i would say so yes

Comment: I got it too work, thanks for putting up with my stupidity... not sure why I didn't get that.

Comment: You are welcome...don't worry i'm also stupid quiete often

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Evaluate $I(\lambda)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty xe^{-\lambda x^2}~dx$, and then differentiate it *n* times with regard to $\lambda$.

Comment: Yup! That is the well-known trick!  +1

Answer (score 0):

$$2 \lambda\int_0^{\infty} x^{2n}xe^{-\lambda x^2} \ dx =\frac{1}{\lambda^n}\int_0^{\infty} (\lambda x^2)^{n}e^{-\lambda x^2} \ d(\lambda x^2)\\\overset{\color{blue}{t= \lambda x^2}}{=}\frac{1}{\lambda^n}\int_0^{\infty} t^{n}e^{-t} \ dt =\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\lambda^n} =\frac{n!}{\lambda^n}$$